# sudo command in startup for Auto CPU Frequency

Tags: 22.04, startup-applications

I see some old answers. Hoping it is simpler in 22.04.

I use

```
sudo auto-cpufreq
```

to manage my CPU to get a better battery backup. I have to run this command in Terminal every time my laptop starts. Wondering whether can I can automate the process so that it starts automatically during every start. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a service for this. Running the command with the `--install` argument installs a service you can start, stop, restart, and reload on start.

```
sudo auto-cpufreq --install
```

and to confirm it runs:

```
systemctl status auto-cpufreq
```

OR if you installed the snap version:

```
systemctl status snap.auto-cpufreq.service.service
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know enough about the deamon part.